Blazor Server App error when logging out after adding authorize attribute
I am deep into making my blazor server app and I wanted to add the attribute authorize to all my pages to make sure my wep app is secure, exluding the login page. However now that I have added this code to my pages whenever I go to logout when on the pages I added the attribute too I get this error:
(Tried to logout when on the account manage page)
This localhost page can’t be foundNo webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:7123/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FAccount%2FManage
I need to mention a few things, I havent added the attriute authorize to the home page and if I click the logout button when on the home page I am logged out fine it is just all the other pages. I also cannot find the Logout file in my project solution anywhere.
Here is the logout button code on the Navmenu:
<div class="nav-item px-3">
    <form action="Account/Logout" method="post">
        <AntiforgeryToken />
        <input type="hidden" name="ReturnUrl" value="@currentUrl" />
        <button type="submit" class="nav-link">
            <span class="bi bi-arrow-bar-left-nav-menu" aria-hidden="true"></span> Logout
        </button>
    </form>
</div>

And I simply added this line of code:
@attribute [Authorize]
I would try to find a solution myself but i cant even find the logout page so i dont even know where to start. I have tried searching for it.
Any help appreciated

try this: action="/Account/Logout"

How would it properly log out, delete the session cookie or whatever for some pages, if there's no logic for it? Is it a custom login page?

@hakim00 the logout page is not custom it is whatever visual studio scaffolded but i cant even find the file anywhere in the account folder or in the project entirly. Not sure how or why it logs the user out if on the home page but not the other pages. It only started to happen when i added attribute [Authorize] to the other pages.

When logout in balzor , there is no specific component for logout, instead it calls MapAdditionalIdentityEndpoints in IdentityComponentsEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions . You could find this through Global search. The issue cannot be reproduced. I started a Blazor server webapp .net8 with rendermode Global, and if I logout at the page I added attribute which is not homepage, It will redirect to login page automatically. You could provide more details  so that we could reproduce it.

I figured it out you need to go to the IdentityComponentsEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.cs file under the account directory. Then you fill find this code with a map post method. I simply removed the ReturnUrl parameter and had it redirect me to the home page manually.
 accountGroup.MapPost("/Logout", async (ClaimsPrincipal user, SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager) =>
 {
     await signInManager.SignOutAsync();
     return TypedResults.LocalRedirect($"~/");
 });


The logout button sends a POST request to Account/Logout, and you've set ReturnUrl to @currentUrl. When you log out from an authorized page, the app might be trying to redirect back to the same page that now requires authentication, leading to a loop or an error page because the user is no longer authenticated.Instead of redirecting back to the current URL after logout, redirect to a public page (e.g., the home page or login page). You can modify the ReturnUrl in the form to point to a known public page:
<form action="Account/Logout" method="post">
<AntiforgeryToken />
<input type="hidden" name="ReturnUrl" value="/" /> <!-- Redirect to home or login page -->
<button type="submit" class="nav-link">
    <span class="bi bi-arrow-bar-left-nav-menu" aria-hidden="true"></span> Logout
</button>

